# Les mots sont-ils majoritairement de longeur paire ?

Tags: lexique

Essayant de m'endormir¹, je jouais avec une pièce virtuelle, censée me donner des résultats aléatoires², en choisissant des mots suffisament longs³ et en mesurant la **parité** du nombre de leurs lettres. Comment mieux perdre son temps, je me le demande.

Le hic arrive quand **après 8 mots** choisis au pif par mon cerveau dégénéré, **aucun n'est encore de longeur impaire**. Ça arrive, certes, mais après encore quelques essais **(25/27)**⁴, ça en devient suffisament improbable pour que je garde ça pour moi.

- Suis-je, moi, biaisé ?
- ***Parmi les mots du dictionnaire, y a-t-il des statistiques à ce sujet ?***

Au chapitre des hypothèses foireuses :

- Le fait que plein de syllabes soient simplement une consonne et une voyelle, et qu'elles forment beaucoup des mots qui viennent le plus facilement à l'esprit (*luminosité*).
- Beaucoup ont des lettres doublées, ou sans cause phonétique évidente, peut-être les mots tendent-ils à respecter cette « règle » ? (*occasion*, *appartenir*, le *e* de *peindre*, et le *o* de *salopard*)
- Les syllabes de 3 lettres semblent aller souvent ensemble, et comme la plupart des mots font peu de syllabes (avant affixes), 3 et 3 font 6 (*maître*, *dormir*, et *universel* qui se laisse emporter).

---

¹ Rarement un échec aura-t-il été aussi magistral…
² Astuce⁶ probablement originellement trouvée pour l'anglais.
³ Sinon on prévoit trop facilement le résultat en ne pouvant s'empêcher de visualiser le mot.

⁴ *Peinture*, *altitude*, *maître-chanteur*, *luminosité*, *formidable*, *maintenant*, *probablement*, *construction*, *salopard* (*salaud*), *oreiller*, *admirablement*, *endormir*, universel, *occasionellement*, *décalage*, *solitude*, *couverture*, *papillon*, *registre*, *constitution*, symphonie, *éprouvette*, *appartenir*, battement, *national*, *pancarte*. Allez-y, psychanalysez.

⁵ Épargnons-nous la morphologie, ou bien et on est pas rendus, et avec deux formes — féminin singulier et masculin pluriel — qui ont le plus souvent +1 lettre, et une avec +2 (féminin pluriel) pour beaucoup de formes de base, on perd un peu en pertinence.

<sub>6 Et bien entendu, une fois qu'on peut générer des bits aléatoires, on a par extension des nombres entre 1 et *n* avec un peu de patience.</sub>

Comment: C'est moi, ou j'ai l'impression que le nombre de notes de pied de page du Vieux Gildas est souvent pair (et trop élevé pour que le texte soit lisible) ?

Comment: Dans ta question, il y a 181 mots de longueur paire contre 119 de longueur impaire. Mais si on se limite aux mots de 3 lettres et plus, on arrive à 116 contre 104.

Comment: @Gilles : Merci. Et si on se limite aux mots de 2 ou 4 lettres ou plus, c'est une toute autre triche que si on prend les mots de 3 lettres. Avec un seuil à 7, ça m'intéresse beaucoup.

Comment: Fréquences pour les mots de 1 à 16 lettres (le maximum) : 15, 65, 36, 30, 25, 24, 26, 37, 11, 17, 4, 6, 2, 1, 0, 1. Il n'y a pas de mot particulier qui explique le pic à 8.

Comment: @Gilles : Avec un [seuil à 6½](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4422/les-mots-sont-ils-majoritairement-de-longeur-paire#comment7950_4423), ça m'intéresse (8) beaucoup (8), et ça donne **73 contre 43**, c'est quand même bien écrasant (8). Ça aurait (6) tendance (8) à désigner (8) mon écriture (8), et c'est facile (6) à relancer (8) sur n'importe (8) quelle (6) autre question (8). (C'est involontaire (12), mais c'est bluffant (8).)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Ça me fait [un hobby](http://xkcd.com/1208/) commun de plus avec Randall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comme suggéré [sur le chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6879542#6879542), voici une analyse sur le lexique de [lexique.org](http://www.lexique.org) en fonction de la longueur des mots. En bleu la fréquence des mots de longueur paire, en orange celle des mots de longueur impaire, pour les mots de longueurs supérieures à l'abscisse. En jaune la fréquence des mots de ces longueurs dans le lexique :

[image: Fréquences comparées en fonction de la longueur minimum]

L'analyse ne tient compte que des lemmes (formes non-fléchies).

On a visiblement toujours un ratio 50/50 à quelques poussières près, surtout dans les longueurs qui ont une fréquence représentative.

**Conclusion** : avec toutes les pincettes possibles, **non, il ne semble pas y avoir de biais en faveur des longueurs paires**.

Pour les sceptiques, le script (sale pour l'instant) est sur [GitHub](https://github.com/Evpok/even-words).

Answer (score 6):

L'un de mes dictionnaires place les mots de longueur impaire et les mots de longueur paire à quasi-égalité (mais cela n'inclut pas leur fréquence).

```
P=0; Q=0; for i in $(aspell dump master fr_FR); do [ $((${#i}%2)) = 0 ] && P=$(($P+1)) || Q=$(($Q+1)); done; echo pair: $P; echo impair: $Q
```

Qui donne :

```
pair: 314692
impair: 314877
```

Et en enlevant les combinaisons qui contiennent une apostrophe :

```
pair: 170861
impair: 170924
```

Comment: Sans tomber sous le coup de la note 5 ? (Joli, cela dit.)

Comment: Now it includes all possible inflections.